# Error Missing concrete implementation of 'StatefulWidget.createState'. Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract

Tags: flutter, dart, stateful, statefulwidget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget { 
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 100,
              color:  Colors.yellow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("asset/image/Bestone.jpg")))));
  }
}
```

No matter what I'm using, I have a problem when I'm trying to run or code. I get this error.

> Missing concrete implementation of 'StatefulWidget.createState'. Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract for the MyApp ()

Answer (score 3):

`StatefulWidget` requires override method `createState` So you must override that method. Remove the build method and specify the following line inside MyApp

```
@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
```

Full example with proper StateFulWidget

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue. When I add the createState() override, that resolves the error but then "Dart Analysis" shows the following warning: Invalid use of a private type in a public API.

Comment: @Keita Share some snippets of what u trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue also.  My code was working just fine until I was making some changes and must have inadvertently removed a curly brace at the end of  } on my initState() function.

Make sure your functions keep the correct scope. VSCODE is a cool editor but when CODEIUM gets going it can easily cause you to make code changes that you might not see or want to do.